# Use SSH to connect from dev pc through server to third party web service

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have a client who has set up a web service on an IP A. He has granted access to it for my server's public IP lets say B.

Is there a way to reach the web service running on IP A through my dev PC (having no public IP) from home?

My server with IP B is an EC2 instance.

Answer (score -1):

If your dev PC is on the internet, you can connect to both IP A and IP B if they are set up to use SSH and have a firewall rule to allow it.

If you want to connect to a machine through another, a simple command such as:
`ssh IP B -t 'ssh IP A'` should work.
You will have to enter two passwords though, unless you use SSH keys.

If your dev PC IS NOT on the internet, then there's of course no way to reach them, unless you SSH into a local machine that DOES have access to the internet. This route seems a bit silly to me though.

Comment: I am not sure this answer explains, in detail, how to accomplish it. The user clearly does not know hot to verify, the configuration currently, nor change the configuration if it isn't currently configured to allow what you describe. This simply does not provide enough information on HOW to be very helpful. *You might want to slow down on the number of answers you are submitting, submitting 5 in less then an hour, is often what gets people in trouble.* I randomly found 2 questions, with answers you submitted, and I am personally not finding neither one of them very helpful since they are vague

Comment: @Ramhound I don't see how it's not detailed enough? I gave a specific command that does what OP wants. Namely connecting to a machine through another. If your point is that I accidentally swapped IP A and B in the command then that is fixed now.